# How to get User name through OpenId in .net

Tags: c#, .net, openid

I am using `DotNetOpenAuth.dll`

```
var openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
var response = openid.GetResponse();

if (response  != null)
{
    var id = StringToGUID(response.ClaimedIdentifier.ToString());           
    Session["UserID"] = id;
    Response.Redirect("EditProfile.aspx");
}
```

I found Id but not User name.

Comment: You should add which libary you are using.

Comment: i am using DotNetOpenAuth.dll

Comment: i think dotnet doesnt do that for you, you'll have to make extra call to the provider.

Comment: ok,thnx i wwill check that,

Comment: @pooja, if you were able to get its answer; kindly post it so people get to know.